# how to print custom values in custom template in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

HI i have created a content type call "mycontent"

it has 2 fields

Label: MyText , Name: mytext , type: Text
Label: MyImage , Name: myimage , type: Image

All good so far, I have create a custom theme and inside this i have included

'node-mycontent.tpl.php'

my quesiton is, how do i get at the variables.

I wish to $mytext

I can render global variables ie $content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might mention that you are using cck, imagefield, filefield (or whateever you are using).

cck automatically adds template variables for custom fields. they are accessible via `$field_<field-name>`, eg. `$field_mytext` and `$field_myimage`. do a `var_dump($variables)` or `var_dump($field_myimage)` etc. in you `node-mycontent.tpl.php` to see how these variables are structured.

[cck for themers](http://drupal.org/node/62462) might also be of help.